# React function is not defined

Tags: function, reactjs, class, google-analytics, components

I am trying to create a react component with imported data from Google API. I can see the code is working in the console.log but when I try to use that code in React render method, I am not getting anything. When I move my function inside the class it comes up as the function not defined. I cannot understand why?

```html
function handleTouchTap() {
  console.log('CHIP selected');
  authorize();
}

function handleAccounts(response) {
  console.log(response.result.username);
  var username = response.result.username
  console.log(username);
}

function authorize(event) {
  var useImmidiate = event ? false : true;
  var authData = {
    client_id: CLIENT_ID,
    scope: SCOPES,
    immidiate: useImmidiate
  };
  gapi.auth.authorize(authData, function (response) {
    gapi.client.load('analytics', 'v3').then(function () {
      console.log(response);
      gapi.client.analytics.management.accounts.list().then(handleAccounts);
    });
  });
}

class Chips extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={styles.wrapper}>
        <Chip
          onTouchTap={handleTouchTap}
          style={styles.chip} >
          <Avatar icon={<FontIcon className="material-icons">perm_identity</FontIcon>} />
          Login
        </Chip>
        <Chip
          style={styles.chip} >
          <Avatar icon={<FontIcon className="material-icons">account_circle</FontIcon>} />
          {this.username}
        </Chip>
      </div>  
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for that. I am not used to StackOverflow. I was trying to post my code but took some time to understand how to do it?

Comment: I don't see the `handleTouchTap` function referenced in `onTouchTap={handleTouchTap}`

Comment: Can you add the error you're getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error with the code I am having above. I am having the username in the console but I want to show the username in the chip @{this.username}. It is not showing any username. I am very Sorry but I cannot attach the screenshot to show you the console because I am not having enough reputation point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases, when you want to render something that might change, you want to add it to the state. That way when you call `setState` the component knows it needs to rerender and show the changes.

Here I added the functions as component methods, so that you can call `this.setState` on the result. Ideally you would probably do this with redux and use actions but this will work as a self contained component.

```
class Chips extends React.Component {
  handleTouchTap = () => {
    console.log('CHIP selected');
    this.authorize();
  }

  handleAccounts = (response) => {
    var username = response.result.username;
    this.setState({
      username
    });
  }

  authorize = (event) => {
    var useImmidiate = event ? false : true;
    var authData = {
      client_id: CLIENT_ID,
      scope: SCOPES,
      immidiate: useImmidiate
    };
    gapi.auth.authorize(authData, (response) => {
      gapi.client.load('analytics', 'v3').then(() => {
        console.log(response);
        gapi.client.analytics.management.accounts.list()
          .then(this.handleAccounts);
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={styles.wrapper}>
        <Chip
          onTouchTap={this.handleTouchTap}
          style={styles.chip}>
          <Avatar icon={<FontIcon className="material-icons">perm_identity</FontIcon>} />
          Login
        </Chip>
        <Chip
          style={styles.chip} >
          <Avatar icon={<FontIcon className="material-icons">account_circle</FontIcon>} />
          {this.state.username}
        </Chip>
      </div>  
    );
  }
}
```